# Page Speed shows high score only first time

Tags: pagespeed-insights

I am trying to understand if there is an expectation of caching of the website that influence the score of Page speed Insight. I am checking my website https://rapidds.com using a browser that is set to clear cache every time browser is closed.

I launch the browser and check performance of https://rapidds.com and consistently get 85% or so every time I try for the first time. All subsequent tries give you very poor results varying from 30 - 50%. If I close the browser and try again, I get high score of >80%. I can reproduce this pretty consistently.

So the question is, is there a caching expectation tied to  the site performance (which need to be configured on the website) to get higher score on subsequent tries. Like if you are trying to access a site that you have already accessed from the same browser, due to this stored cache, second time site should load faster then it originally did. And as https://rapidds.com is missing the configuration, it is getting poor score on subsequent tries?

Comment: Just a quick one, when you close the browser and then reopen it do you actually go to page speed insights and type the URL into the input box, or do you use auto complete in the URL bar and press enter to test? I consistently get low scores for you no matter what variations of opening and closing browsers, incognito etc. I perform so my only though is you have a saved URL with the desktop tab selected and then when you rerun it is showing the mobile version. Other than that is it that you are using Page Speed Insights website / API or are you using "Lighthouse" in the browser.

Comment: What I mean is when you open the browser and test you don't see `&tab=desktop` at the end of the page speed insights URL do you? ("https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?url=https%3A%2F%2Frapidds.com%2F&tab=desktop") That is the only logical explanation I can think of is that you are loading the desktop test on first run, then pressing "analyze" again and that will then show the mobile by default.

Comment: You are spot on. Somehow I did not notice the toggle between mobile and desktop UI check which it does upon Refresh. Thank you.

Comment: Not a problem at all, it is an easy thing to overlook! Good luck with the project.